# Construir conexión a mysql en Java con parámetros

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

estoy importando archivos .csv a tablas en MySQL desde Workbench con el siguiente código

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'path/ejemplo.csv'
INTO TABLE temp_tags
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

El punto es que sí funciona normal la importación de datos desde WorkBench únicamente si antes edito mi conexión de mysql y agrego esta línea en Advanced > Others

[image: Línea adicional]

Si no agrego esa línea a mi conexión en mysql workbench me tira error de secure-priv-file pero bueno ya no es problema con esa línea que se agrega a la conexión.

Ahora quiero ejecutar ese LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE pero desde una conexión hecha en Java con un PreparedStatement, ya he conectado antes a una base de datos desde Java pero nunca le había tenido que poner algún parámetro adicional, así es mi código para la conexión desde Java:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces ahora que necesito conectarme desde java con:

```
OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1
```

¿Cómo tendría que quedar mi conexión con el parámetro anterior añadido desde Java?
Gracias, saludos.

Comment: Hola @ÁngelAlonso la opción `OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1` es para solventar un bug en  `Workbench ` conectarte con Java Jdbc es totalmente diferente, entonces no necesitas agregar esa opción para realizar tus operaciones CRUD.

Comment: [Aquí están detalladas las propiedades que puedes establecer desde la conexión](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html). No sé si ahí entre `OPT_LOCAL_INFILE` en caso de necesitarlo. Si no puedes hacerlo desde la conexión, podría establecerse quizá por medio de una consulta SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en efecto la opción `OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1` no fue necesaria añadirla como parametro en java, lo que me faltaba añadir era `allowLoadLocalInfile=true` pues me daba

> error: Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides.

Al final quedó como mencioné en un principio pero con el parámetro allowLoadLocalInfile=true

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL + DB_NAME + "?allowLoadLocalInfile=true", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);`

Saludos.

Comment: Buen hallazgo! Recuerda marcar tu respuesta como aceptada para que otros sepan en el futuro cómo lograr esto mismo.

Comment: De acuerdo @Alfabravo, la verdad apenas soy nuevo en stackoverflow, gracias jajaja